# Select entries where count = 0

Tags: sql, join, count

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I've got 2 tables for a hotel system database, the "Rooms" table and the "Guests" table.

The Rooms table has a room_number column, for the number of that room (primary key).
The Guests table has a room_number column, for the room number that guest is staying (foreign key).

I need a query which returns only the room numbers of rooms which have no guests staying in them.

At the moment I have this:

```
SELECT Rooms.room_number, COUNT(Guests.guest_id) AS occupant_count 
From Rooms,Guests 
WHERE (Rooms.room_number = Guests.room_number)
```

This returns all occupant counts. How can I get it to return only the room numbers of rooms which have no guests in them?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where is your `GROUP BY` clause? Add the `GROUP BY` and then add `HAVING COUNT(Guests.guest_id) = 0` and you're done.

Comment: Yes its trivial rather than silly. And I don't think it's fair to mark the o/p down for asking what he doesn't know about (upvoted back to zero)!

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm mostly fine with simple SQL, clearly I need more practice using GROUP BY clauses, among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trivial rather than silly.

```
SELECT Rooms.room_number 
From Rooms 
WHERE Rooms.room_number not in ( select Guests.room_number 
                                 from Guests)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do an outer join between the two tables and add `AND Guests.room_number is null` to the end of your query.